# How to change the icon on google map, while the layer is import by kml file?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been trying to solve this question for a week, and haven't found any solution yet.

All I found is marker that is placed by one's own can be changed.

My situation is I import a KML file with some marker,and I want to change the icon on click event.
The code below works fine

```
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            //KMZ KML
            url: url,
            map: map,
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
         });
    ctaLayer.addListener('click', function (kmlEvent) {     
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;  
    showInContentWindow(text); }
```

[My Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpcKd.png)

Most People use the below function to set different icon

```
marker.seticon(ICON)
```

But in my case I can't get the marker I click

Hope someone can help me!!

Comment: can you add more detail? What did you try, what is a difficulty for you?

Comment: you should make fiddle of your code to make it easy for everyone to help you. https://jsfiddle.net/   or insert code Snippet along with your question

Comment: have a look at this (http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/scSMr/) it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) you can't change the style after load (with the API as currently documented).  One option would be to use a third party KML parser (like geoxml3 or geoxml_v3) which converts KML into native google maps api objects, which you can change.

geoxml3:
https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3

geoxml_v3:
http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/

Comment: so there 's no way that I can solve this without using a third party KML parser??

Comment: A KmlLayer is not very dynamic, you could load a different KML file based on the click event or maybe put a marker over top of the one in the KML.

Answer (score 1):

According to geocodezip's advice

I came out with this solution

```
        var marker;
        google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function (event) {

            var eLatLng = event.latLng;     

             if (marker != null) //this will remove the previous marker
            {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: eLatLng,
                map: map,

            });

            marker.setPosition((eLatLng));
            marker.setIcon(ICON);
        });
```

While clicking the kmlLayer marker,I overlay a new bigger marker on it.

I know it's not the best solution, but at least it tells users which marker they are now clicking.

Comment: You can use the [KmlMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlMouseEvent) data to make the position of the marker more accurate and add an InfoWindow (if you want one).

Comment: I put the content of infoWindow at the left inside a<div>,but still appreciate of your advice.